# How to stop propagating event from parent div to child div

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I want to stop propagate event from parent `div` to child `div` in my html. Here a simple code what I'm trying to do:

```
<div>
  <div id='categoryList'>
    <div class='listed-category'>
      <span>some content</span>
      <a id='close'>x</a> //"a" is used to remove the div
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id='dropdown'>
</div>
```

In the above code if I click on `<div id='categoryList'>` the `<div id='dropdown'>` will slide-up and down by bellow code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#categoryList').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        if ($('#dropdown').is(":visible")) {
            $('#dropdown').slideUp(400);
        }
        else {
            $('#dropdown').slideDown(400);
        }
    });
})
```

But when I click on the child `<div class='listed-category'>` the above JavaScript executes and the `<div id='dropdown'>` is sliding up and down. How to stop this? Yet I want to be able to click on `<a id='close'>` to remove the child `div`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Check target for match clicked object. Try this code in beginning of click event handler.

```
if( event.target !== this ) {
       return;
}
//...do stuff..
```

Comment: best solution by far here -- better than the built in apis that kinda sorta dont do what you want

Comment: I'd suggest using `event.target !== event.currentTarget` rather than `this` as `this`'s context could be rebinded.

Comment: Brilliant solution. Ezio's suggestion works, too.

Answer (score 6):

you need to stop propagating in child,not parent so you should write this:

```
 $('.listed-category').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

and if you want to click `a` tag and stop propagation too,you also need to write this:

```
 $('a#close').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Anyways I will suggest Yuriy's answer. I just want you to know that you should put `event.stopPropagation()` in childrens(if you don't want event of parent is run),instead of parent.

Comment: and if there is will be 3-4 childrens, then we need to add more event handlers?

Comment: @YuriyNedostup yes,your way is better than mine. I just want to make him know that he should put event.stopPropagation() in childrens,not parent.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is correct but in a best scenario when you have multiple nested elements, You would like to not cancel the event but to get the actual clicked parent container and work with it.

```
$('.clicked-container').click((e) => {
    let t = e.target;
    while (!$(t).hasClass( "clicked-container" )) { t = t.parentNode; }
     
    ...
    $(t).toggleClass('active-or-whatever-you-want');
});
```

Also "this" in the accepted answer doesn't refer anymore to the same thing when you use Arrows => in ES6. You have to explicitly bind this.

Comment: Ps. Don't try it on the HTML element ;-)

Answer (score 2):

A more elegant solution is to use **CSS** and disable the pointer events on the children.

```
#categoryList * {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Or in your specific case to have no events on the `listed-category` element:

```
#listed-category {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://codepen.io/rakeshcode/pen/KrZdNo

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".arrow").click(function(){
  $(".row").slideToggle();
  
  });

$(".btn").click(function(event){
   event.stopPropagation();
  //$(".btn").attr("href","www.yahoo.com")
});
})
```

```css
.btn {
  display: block;
  padding:15px;
  background-color:green;
  width:100px;
  margin-top:15px;
  text-decoration:none;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  
  
  
}
.arrow {
  cursor:pointer;
  text-align: center;
  padding:10px 0;
  font-size:15px;
  font-weight:bold;
  background-color:grey;
  margin-top:15px;
}
.container {
  max-width:600px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto; 
}
.close {
  height:75px;
  overflow:hidden;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;  
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
}
.open {
  height:215px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition-property:height;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;  
  transition-timing-function: ease-in;
}
.up {
  background-color:red; 
}
.down {
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="arrow"> Click here Click here<a class="btn" href="www.google.com" target="_blank">click here</a></div>
  <div class="wrap">
  <div class="row">The most effective plac elearning,’ they most likely don’t know this themselves.Well, the most effective place to start is to dig into what the person asking for this training, ACTUALLY needs. Because if they’re dumping a huge stack of content on your desk and giving you vague instructions to ‘turn it into elearning,’ they most likely don’t know this themselves.Well, the most effective place to start is to dig into what the person asking for this training.ACTUALLY needs. Because if they’re dumping a huge stack of content on your desk and giving you vague instructions to ‘turn it into elearning,’ they most likely don’t know this themselves.Well, the most effective place to start is to dig into what the person asking for this trainingACTUALLY needs. Because if they’re dumping a huge stack of content on your desk and giving you vague instructions to ‘turn it into elearning,’ they most likely don’t know this themselves.Well, the most effective place to start is to dig into what the person asking for this training</div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Here is the example

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using e.stopPropagation, I suggest you to use unbind() method in the div `<div class='listed-category'>` like so...

```
$('.listed-category').unbind('click');
```

This will allow to stop the propagation effect for the `.listed-category` div. The method `e.stopPropagation()` doesn't work because it just works with parent elements and not with child elements.

You can always create a new function and assign to the `.listed-category` div afterwards.. You can also check the documentation for the `unbind()` method at this link: http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

#### An example of preventing event bubbling using ref on React:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";

const Modal = ({
  onClick,
}) => {
  const modalRef = useRef();

  return (
    <div
      ref={modalRef}
      onClick={(e) => {
        if (e.target !== modalRef.current) {
          return;
        }
        onClick();
      }}
    >
    </div>
  );
};

export default Modal;
```

#### Reference

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28210173/5994546