# How to prevent a click from triggering multiple click handler calls in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using jQuery for a list and a div element click. HTML code is-

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <div>
            <div>
                Anything <img id="image_click" src="http://www.neatimage.com/im/lin_logo.gif">
            </div>
            <div>
                More thing
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Documents</li>        
    <li class="list-group-item">Music</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Videos</li>
</ul>
```

And jQuery code is-

```
$( document ).ready(function()
{
    $(".list-group-item").click(function()
    {
        alert($("For list");
    });

    $("#image_click").click(function()
    {
        alert("for image");
    });
});
```

When I click on a li item, only **For list** is alerted.
But if I clicked on image, then **for image** and after that **For list** is alerted.

What I want is if anyone click on li element, **For list** should be alerted, but if he clicks on the image, only **for image** should be alerted, **for list** should not be alerted.

Comment: Here is Fiddle Link http://jsfiddle.net/kcL8e3d0/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because of [event bubbling](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-bubbling), so you stop it by calling [Event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation)

```
$("#image_click").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert("for image");
});
```

Comment: Isn't stopping propagation not a good idea to do? Shouldn't there be a better way to handle this? http://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/

Comment: @crazymatt you can always check whether the click happened in a particular element and then choose not to do anything

Comment: @crazymatt something like - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gyr6g1p1/1/ - or more generalized http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gyr6g1p1/2/

Answer (score 1):

use **[stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)**; : to stop bubbling event

```
 $("#image_click").click(function(e)
    {
       e.stopPropagation();
        alert("for image");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try this code:

```
$(".list-group-item").click(function (e) {
    if(this==e.target)
         alert("for list");
});
```

I think this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28210108/how-to-stop-propagating-event-from-parent-div-to-child-div) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want any action from any action that simply write `return false`. which will prevent from multiple triggering your function code.

```
 $(".list-group-item").click(function(){
       return false;
    });

$("#image_click").click(function(){
     alert("for image");
});
```

Comment: Read this article http://philipwalton.com/articles/the-dangers-of-stopping-event-propagation/