# Javascript onsubmit triggers parent onclick

Tags: javascript, onclick, submit, onsubmit

I have a html page with a table and a form in each row. When i klick on the row it should open a detailpage, but when I click in the form this should not be triggered.

My row looks like this:

```
<tr onclick="window.parent.location.href='details.php?id=123';"><td><img /></td><td>text</td><td>price<br>
  <form method="post">
    <input type="number" name="size" value="1">
    <input type="submit" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure?');">
  </form>
</td></tr>
```

So it should work like this: if I klick in the size-field, or on the submit-button, the detail-page should not be called.

I found out that one can use event.stopPropagation() for this, but I cannot find out how to do it with plain javascript although it seems that there should be an easy solution

Comment: I don't fully understand, you wouldn't to use a function inside `onclick=""` ? Like `onclick="goToPage('details.php?id=123')"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<tr onclick="window.parent.location.href='details.php?id=123';">
    <td><img /></td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>price<br> 
        <form method="post" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure?');"> 
            <input type="number" name="size" value="1" onclick="event.stopPropagation()"> 
            <input type="submit" onclick="event.stopPropagation()"> 
        </form> 
    </td>
</tr>
```

Note: Remove the onsubmit from `input` element and add it to form element. Thank you @epascarello for the correction.

Comment: why does a button have an onsubmit handler? That is not correct.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It was in the code @E. Reuter posted. Thanks for correcting :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution

```
<tr onclick="var x = event.clientX;var y = event.clientY;if(document.elementFromPoint(x, y).tagName.toLowerCase()!='input'){window.parent.location.href='details.php?id=123'; }"><td><img /></td><td>text</td><td>price<br>
  <form method="post">
    <input type="number" name="size" value="1">
    <input type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');">
  </form>
</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue myself and this post helped me: [How to stop propagating event from parent div to child div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28210108/how-to-stop-propagating-event-from-parent-div-to-child-div)

So you'll want to set something up like this:

```js
var parent = document.getElementsByClassName("parent")[0];
var child = document.getElementsByClassName("child")[0];

parent.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  alert("you clicked parent"); 
  if (e.target !== this) {
    return;
  }

  e.stopPropagation();
  // parent.style.color = "green";
});

child.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  alert("you clicked child"); 
  if (e.target !== this) {
    return;
  }

  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
}
.child {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px; 
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

In your case, maybe try including a script with functions to call for the onclick element properties for better readability:

```
<tr onclick="changeLocation(e, 'details.php?id=123')"><td><img /></td><td>text</td><td>price<br>
  <form method="post">
    <input type="number" name="size" value="1">
    <input type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');">
  </form>
</td></tr>

<script>
function changeLocation(e, reference) {
      if (e.target !== this) {
        return;
      }

      e.stopPropagation();

    window.parent.location.href=reference;
}
</script>
```

Or even better a propagation event function:

```
<tr onclick="stopProp(this); window.parent.location.href='details.php?id=123';"><td><img /></td><td>text</td><td>price<br>
  <form method="post">
    <input type="number" name="size" value="1">
    <input type="submit" onclick="stopProp(this); return confirm('Are you sure?');">
  </form>
</td></tr>

<script>
function stopProp(e) {
      if (e.target !== this) {
        return;
      }

      e.stopPropagation();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all - I used the solution of sanketd617 and it worked fine - sorry for the error with the onsubmit - in my file it is in the -tag - I typed it and did not copy/paste the code, since my code is a bit more complicated.

I also tried the code of Aricha but it did not work for me - it still did execute the detail-page, but maybe I made a mistake there too. I tried similar solutions before, but it never worked for me.

But I did not find the really simple solution with onclick="event.stopPropagation()" in the onclick of the input-elements. So thank you very much