# Blur event triggered by click on child element

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I got a parent element containing an input:

```
<div @blur="onLeaveSelect($event)">
    <div v-if="searchActivated" >
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." @mousedown.stop>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

When now clicking on the `input` child element the `blur` event of the parent `div` is fired. How'd I prevent that behavior? Using `click.stop` to prohibit bubbling works for other elements, but not that input.

```
        const onLeaveSelect = (evt) => {
            if (!evt.currentTarget.contains(evt.relatedTarget)) {
                open.value = false;
                showDescription.value = false;
                searchActivated.value = false;
            }
        }
```

Like this I stopped the dropdown from closing by a click on the input event.
But the problem now is that `focusing` the input counts as not focusing the parent div anymore, what prevents the blur from getting detected completely.

Comment: why is the blur there (what is its purpose/intention)?

Comment: @depperm It's used for closing a dropdown menu.

Comment: why not place that closer to the dropdown menu?

Comment: @depperm I don't quite get what you mean. The div with the blur event includes the whole dropdown for easy closing it on a click outside.

Comment: can you include the whole div content and include the expected behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution for all of my problems was the `focusout` event. It also detects focus inside an `input` child element. [focusout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focusout_event)

Answer (score 5):

I wanted the same behavior. But the `focusout` event is not present in React.

The way I solved it is using the `onBlur` event with a check to see if any child element is the `relatedTarget`:

- If it's `null`, a child element hasn't been clicked on (so, we will want to hide the drop-down)
- If it's not `null`, a child element has been clicked on (this will prevent the drop-down from being hidden)

Code snippet showing the parent `div`:

```
<div
    tabIndex='-1'
    onBlur={e => e.relatedTarget === null && setState(false)}
>
...
</div>
```

Comment: Gave you +1 for the nice solution. but it is not working for me (maybe bc my child element is absolute)

Answer (score 1):

That happens because of events bubbling so that they get propagated to the parents.

There's an interesting question here on SO that I happened to hit very often in the past: [How to stop propagating event from parent div to child div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28210108/how-to-stop-propagating-event-from-parent-div-to-child-div)

There are several ways to stop such propagation but probably the easiest to achieve in this case is to use the css attribute on your child element:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

But since you clearly need that input to fire events, maybe you could try this other option in the event handler you added to parent element:

```
  if(event.target !== event.currentTarget) return;
```

But if yet you can't achieve what you are aiming to, you may try this line inside the handler for the event you wish it didn't propagate to the parent element:

```
 event.stopPropagation();
```

And as a side note I realized that div are not used to have the blur event because they don't capture focus as long as they don't have any tabindex="0" or contentEditable attributes. Maybe that's set by that directive when it will render the real html.

Comment: But like this it also ain't possible to focus the `input` anymore cuase I got no pointer events at all. And chaning the values for the input and it's surrounding div ddin't do the trick.

Comment: With the other option I'm just checking if the parent element itself is clicked. But cause it's a blur event I want it to fire when not clicking the element itself. It's tricky...

Answer (score -1):

This is called event bubbling, to stop the event propagations, use e.stopPropagation() method on the child onClick()